# Digit grouping -- Apostrophe or space as decimal point

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Today, I had to deal with large number blocks with >10 digits. With my current setup, the whole number is shown without any grouping or decimal point, making it hard to read them, especially when they contain large amounts of zeros.

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt,]{scrartcl} 
% Für Spracheingaben und korrekte Trennung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Matherelevante Pakete
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Sonstige Parameter
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
```

As you can see, I’m using commas as the regular decimal symbol, so a comma as a decimal point wouldn’t make too much sense.

Anyway, how do I get digits to be grouped automatically? So far, I’ve been using the following, manual way to achieve spacing between larger numbers, but that isn’t too comfortable:

```
\sqrt[2]{1,6 \cdot 10^{13}} = \sqrt[2]{16\,000\,000\,000\,000} &= 4\,000\,000\
```

[image: intended ouput]

So my question is: How do I get automatic digit grouping with the decimal point being either an apostrophe or a non-braking space?

Comment: \usepackage{siunitx} and \num{12345,67890} -> 12 345.678 90 \\

Comment: The apostrophe or the upper dot for separating groups of digits are frowned upon in typographic circles. A thin space is the best separator and, as @LaRaison says, it's provided by `siunitx` with the macro `\num`, possibly passing some options.

Comment: @LaRaison: That still is rather manual. Also, I think it is awkward to have \num{} within equation- or align-brackets

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu: Still much better than entering it manually, I think. A fully automatic solution would require turning digits into active characters, this might be very very fragile.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu I don't think it's difficult to write: `$\sqrt{\num{1.6e13}} = \sqrt{\num{16 000 000 000 000}} = \num{4 000 000}$`. You can separate groups also in the input and `\num` will take care of reformatting them independently of the input format. If you have many decimal numbers it's even handier than relying on `icomma`: you can use either a comma or a dot in the input and the number will be formatted as requested with the options passed to `siunitx`.

Comment: @egreg Using `\num{12345,67890}` results in 12345.67890 being shown using the preamble shown in my initial question. Which option am I missing?

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu The `decimalsymbol` option is proper of version 1 of `siunitx` and forces it to use version 1 features. If you're not stuck with that version because of an outdated TeX distribution, it's better to use `output-decimal-marker={,}` for setting the comma.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `siunitx` package you're already loading provides the `\num` command for formatting numbers.

This command is very handy, because it allows to get output independently on how the input is formatted.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt,]{scrartcl}
% Für Spracheingaben und korrekte Trennung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Matherelevante Pakete
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,},exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Sonstige Parameter
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{\num{1.6e13}} = \sqrt{\num{16 000 000 000 000}} = \num{4 000 000}$

$\sqrt{\num{1,6e13}} = \sqrt{\num{16000000000000}} = \num{4000000}$

\end{document}
```

The two inputs will give the same output, namely

[image]

Note that `decimalsymbol=comma` is a "version 1" option, so it forces `siunitx` to use only the less powerful features present in version 1. The options I passed in the example are the "modern" ones.

In case you're stuck with the old version because of an outdated TeX distribution, update it or use

```
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma,expproduct=\cdot]{siunitx}
```

In any case, *never* use anything other than thin spaces for separating groups of digits.

Comment: Thank you very much. From now on, I’m trying to use `\num{}`in [tag:math-mode].

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu Decimal numbers and "big" numbers, of course. There's no point in using `\num` to write `\sqrt{42}`; but for the said kinds of numbers it's very handy to be "input independent": for instance, you can change from "decimal comma" to "decimal period" just changing *one* option to `siunitx`.

Comment: However, when using `sqrt{\num{1.6e13}}` prior to `\sqrt{1.6\cdot10^{13}}`, the height changes, where `e13` makes the root box higher: [picture](http://i.imgur.com/nE5Ev.png) – which one is, typographically speaking, “looking better”? I prefer the smaller one, to be honest.

Comment: TeXnically speaking, the difference is due to the fact that `\sqrt` forces "cramped" style in its argument, which results in lowering superscripts if they're not accompanied by subscripts, while `\num` resurrects the "uncramped" style. I prefer the "uncramped" style, to be honest.

Comment: Is using `\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}` equal to using `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker=\cdot}` after including the package (without options)?

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu Yes, that's the same; options can always be specified with `\sisetup` also in the middle of the document. This can be handy in a multilingual document, for instance. An option can also be set locally as optional argument to `\num`, `\si` or `\SI`.